# Controlled Radio Group Button updates only 1st group when value of other radio group gets changed - in React

Tags: reactjs, toggle, radio-group

Here I'm trying to render a table of members having 3 radio buttons for each member (Attending, Tentative, Not Attending) along with it's name.

I've saved each memberRow's state in `option` state var & was expecting when I update option of 2nd member, it updates the 1st one.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/swsessaji/aruhtdsk/4/)

Comment: Do you want that if you select an option from 1 row then all rows must show the same option selected?

Comment: @DhavalGajjar No, each row's option should be independent of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the id in your `input` tag. You must use a unique id in each input tag and each row. In `label` you use `htmlFor` as the id is not unique in rows it will always point out to the first id match. So your case it will be the first row. So change is always reflected in the first row only.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const RowAction = ({ member, index }) => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState(member.response);

  const onRadioChange = (e) => {
    let selected;
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "1":
        selected = 1;
        break;
      case "-1":
        selected = -1;
        break;
      case "0":
        selected = 0;
        break;
      default:
        selected = null;
    }
    setOption(selected);
  };
  return (
    <tr key={member.name}>
      <td>{member.name}</td>
      <td>
        <div className="switch-field">
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={`attending${index}`}
            value={1}
            checked={option === 1}
            onChange={onRadioChange}
          />
          <label
            htmlFor={`attending${index}`}
            className={option === 1 ? "attending" : ""}
          >
            ATTENDING
          </label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={`tentative${index}`}
            value={-1}
            checked={option === -1}
            onChange={onRadioChange}
          />
          <label
            htmlFor={`tentative${index}`}
            className={option === -1 ? "tentative" : ""}
          >
            TENTATIVE
          </label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={`notAttending${index}`}
            value={0}
            checked={option === 0}
            onChange={onRadioChange}
          />
          <label
            htmlFor={`notAttending${index}`}
            className={option === 0 ? "notattending" : ""}
          >
            NOT ATTENDING
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default RowAction;
```

Working sample https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-darkness-posvv7

Comment: Ok..The power of ids... Thanks @Dhaval